# .NET 4.5 HTTPWebRequest - Intermittent slowdowns with a large number of simultaneous HTTPS POST requests

Tags: .net, https, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I have a large number (50+) of threads which make HTTPS POST requests to a web api to poll different data sets as fast as possible. It works fine half of the time, but for the other half there will be a hiccup where the bandwidth used by the application goes down significantly.

**Update 1**
The code listed below isnt current anymore, it was modified per Domin8urMind recommendation.

So I've looked at all the traffic in fiddler. Once a slow down starts I notice that my client establishes new HTTPS tunnels, and the slowdown ends after the new tunnels have been established. The 50+ tunnels which are established when the program first start takes only about 1 second to establish, but during a slowdown it takes aproximately 30 seconds to establish all the tunnels. This re-establishment/slowdown seems to happen like clock work every 2 minutes.

Also i've noticed that a CDN sits in between my client and the server, and that it does have DoS protection. I am unsure if this performance issue is either related to my code, or to the CDN.

So I guess my questions now would be:

- Under what conditions will a HTTPWebRequest's HTTPS connections be closed when the keep alive and pipelining features are enabled?
- Why is it taking so long for these connections to be re-established?

**myMethod**

```
private static string myMethod(string method, Dictionary<string, string> paramList = null, int maxRetryCount = 1)
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 400;
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("My URL");
    String postData = "My POST Data"

    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Timeout = 1000;
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    request.Proxy = null;

    try
    {
        Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
        stream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        Stream decompressedStream = null;
        if (response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip"))
            decompressedStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
        else if (response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("deflate"))
            decompressedStream = new DeflateStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
        else
            decompressedStream = responseStream;

        StreamReader postreqreader = new StreamReader(decompressedStream);
        var json = postreqreader.ReadToEnd();

        postreqreader.Close();
        decompressedStream.Close();
        responseStream.Close();

        return json;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if(e.Message != "The operation has timed out")
            Console.Write("\nGot exception " + e.Message + " " + e.StackTrace + "\n\n\n");
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

**Exception 1**

```
Got exception The request was aborted: The request was canceled.    at System.Ne
t.GZipWrapperStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
   at myMethod in myFile:line 337
```

Line 337 is "var json = postreqreader.ReadToEnd();"

**Exception 2**

```
Got exception Safe handle has been closed    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.S
afeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean& success)
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle pHandle, Boolea
n& success)
   at System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.setsockopt(SafeCloseSocket socket
Handle, SocketOptionLevel optionLevel, SocketOptionName optionName, Int32& optio
nValue, Int32 optionLength)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel optionLevel, S
ocketOptionName optionName, Int32 optionValue, Boolean silent)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.SetSocketTimeoutOption(SocketShutdown mod
e, Int32 timeout, Boolean silent)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.DrainSocket()
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean abort
ing)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState closeSta
te)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetAndOrProcessResponse(Object responseOrExcepti
on)
   at System.Net.ConnectionReturnResult.SetResponses(ConnectionReturnResult retu
rnResult)
   at System.Net.Connection.ReadComplete(Int32 bytesRead, WebExceptionStatus err
orStatus)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetriev
edStream, Boolean probeRead)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.ProcessWriteCallDone(ConnectionReturnResult retur
nResult)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckDeferredCallDone(ConnectStream stream)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at myMethod in myFile:line 325
```

Line 325 is "HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you change your code using the "using" clause which will close connections correctly, something like:

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("My URL");

using (HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
{
  using (Stream stream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
  {
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

The problem you are having with your existing loop is that when you **catch an exception, the connection is not disposed of correctly and you would need to wait for the Garbage Collector to cleanup these connections before being able to create another**.

I suspect that is your delay. You can verify this by watching the .net GC counter in perfmon and if '% in GC' is spiking during these "slow downs", then you have your culprit .

Comment: I've made those changes, but it hasn't fixed the issue with the slowdown. After making the changes, the % Time In GC counter doesn't spike during a slowdown. I didn't check to see if it did before the changes. And i've started to receive System.ObjectDisposedException when getting the response from the request.

Comment: And to follow up on that exception I am now receiving, from what i've read it happens when you try to reuse a WebRequest, but I dont see how my code could possibly be trying to reuse it.

Comment: I've updated my question with new information about what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: Make sure you dispose of the DeflateStream and GZipStream as well. The new questions you have posted have more to do with your service provider. I would emulate it all locally to verify your code, then point outside of your datacenter to see if it's an ISP/firewall issue.

Comment: Yes I am disposing of the deflate/gzip streams. I'll see what I can do about testing it locally but that'll require a bit of work. If it turns out that this was a issue with the CDN flagging my traffic as suspicious i'll award your answer as correct for the points, since you did point out a few things I was doing wrong.